# Coordinates problems

Tags: data, trimble

I have some data that I collected from Trimble Juno 3D. When I download the data, I could not see them in the map. The coordinates are NOT in the correct place where it should be. Their coordinates are like this:

```
Long. -2.652497e+014; 
 Lat. 3.569410e+014.
```

Is it possible change it to decimal degree?

Comment: No. I use ArcMap. I just connect GPS to my PC as always.

Comment: No. I use trimble Juno 3D Handheld

Comment: Sorry. Arcpad 10

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.